# Use native Excel Icons in Excel Addin JS Addin

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, exceljs

I am building an Excel Addin, using Excel JS Api.

Is it possible to somehow reference a native Excel Icon inside manifest use it in the Addin?
I know it is possible to reference by name in VSTO Addins but I doubt whether it is possible to do the same in an Office JS Addin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference in the manifest an icon file that your add-in does not host itself. If you want to use a native Excel icon, you need to make a copy of it as a png or jpg file and reference your copy in the manifest.